# PHP form (post request) through Ajax isn't saving image path to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Hi I've been working on a Php form (index.php) that sends an Ajax request to another Php file (create_product.php) which then saves the information to a mysql database. But the issue is while all the information is being saved to the database the image path isn't and the image isn't being moved to the specified location either.

**I also receive these 2 error messages:**

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\laragon\www\Primespot\includes\create_product.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\laragon\www\Primespot\includes\create_product.php on line 21

**However the print_r($_POST) returns this which clearly shows the image path is there:**

Array ( [title] => New Product [price] => 945 [image] => C:\fakepath\flc765.jpg [desc] => This is the description [category] => Product [qty] => 10 )

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but any help would be much appreciated.

Here's the code

**index.php**

```
<?php include './template-parts/header.php'; ?>

<div class="form_wrapper" id="create_pdt_wrapper">
    <form class="form create_pdt" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input class="input" id="title" type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title">
        <input class="input" id="price" type="number" step="0.01" name="price" placeholder="Price">
        <input class="input" id="image" type="file" name="image">
        <textarea class="textarea" name="desc" id="desc" cols="30" rows="20" placeholder="Write a short Description"></textarea>
        <input class="input" id="category" type="text" name="category" placeholder="Category">
        <input class="input" id="qty" type="number" name="qty">
        <span onclick="createProduct()" class="create">Create</span>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="msg" id="createMsg"></div>

<?php include './template-parts/footer.php'; ?>
```

**create_pdt.js**

```
function createProduct() {
        var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
        var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
        var image = document.getElementById('image').value;
        var desc = document.getElementById('desc').value;
        var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
        var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;
    
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = 'includes/create_product.php';
        var params = 'title='+title+'&price='+price+'&image='+image+'&desc='+desc+'&category='+category+'&qty='+qty;
        http.open('POST', url, true);
    
        //Send the proper header information along with the request
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    
        http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("createMsg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
        }
        http.send(params);
    }
```

**create_product.php**

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "primespot";


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


print_r($_POST);

$pdt_title = $_POST['title'];
$pdt_price = $_POST['price'];
$pdt_image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$tempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name']; 
$pdt_desc = $_POST['desc'];
$pdt_category = $_POST['category'];
$pdt_qty = $_POST['qty'];


move_uploaded_file($tempname, "../img/$pdt_image");

$sql = "INSERT INTO products(pdt_title, pdt_price, pdt_image, pdt_desc, pdt_category, pdt_qty)
VALUES('{$pdt_title}','{$pdt_price}','{$pdt_image}','{$pdt_desc}','{$pdt_category}','{$pdt_qty}' ) ";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Product Created";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Here's the error and the print_r($_POST)
[image]

Comment: dump your file like var_dump($_FILES['image']); die; and post here pls

Comment: var_dump($_FILES['image']); die; is returning NULL along with the previous error messages:           
                                                                           
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\laragon\www\Primespot\includes\create_product.php on line 20

Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\laragon\www\Primespot\includes\create_product.php on line 21
NULL

Comment: Your ajax is wrong. You pass value into params but send files with ajax is different. You need use new FormData(). File is not string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we know, we should pass all file binary content via AJAX call to create_product.php via $_FILES array.

In your original AJAX call, no binary data are passed to the https/http server, ie, to create_product.php, in which $_FILES was empty array.

We modify the **create_pdt.js** file as follows:

```
function createProduct() {
    //var title = document.getElementById('title').value;
    //var price = document.getElementById('price').value;
    //var image = document.getElementById('image').value;
    //var desc = document.getElementById('desc').value;
    //var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    //var qty = document.getElementById('qty').value;

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'includes/create_product.php';
    //var params = 'title='+title+'&price='+price+'&image='+image+'&desc='+desc+'&category='+category+'&qty='+qty;
    http.open('POST', url, true);

    var objForm = document.getElementsByClassName("create_pdt")[0];
    var objFormData = new FormData(objForm);

    //Send the proper header information along with the request
    //
    //COMMENT this to let browser setting by default for file upload:
    //
    //http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("createMsg").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    }
    //http.send(params);
    http.send(objFormData);
}
```

The key change is using FormData object,

```
var objForm = document.getElementsByClassName("create_pdt")[0];
var objFormData = new FormData(objForm);
```

objForm gets the form object you want to post. The second line objFormData englobes all data input in the form object, including image binary data, they are all passed to the AJAX call.

And also, all content-type header settings are removed, here commented:

```
//http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

No changes are required for index.php and create_product.php.

Comment: I'm getting undefined Index error (same one I got for image) for all the inputs when I use FormData()

Comment: I've tested in my server, it worked. Have you saved your create_pdt.js and replace it as whole ? I've done print_r($_FILES) in create_product.php, it was good. and also http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); is commented. When choosing refado6.1.png as file input, print_r($_FILES) gives: Array ( [image] => Array ( [name] => refado6.1.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => C:\Windows\Temp\php448.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 8733 ) )

: REMOVE ALL http.setRequestHeader()...

Comment: Yes It finally worked! Thanks a lot. Looks like the http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); line was the problem. After commenting it out all the data has been saved and the image has been moved to the specified folder.